# MST vs SPT for a 2 vertex graph

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, trees, discrete-optimization

I have a graph with 2 vertices. They each have a directed weighed edge towards the other vertex. One of the weights is higher than the other. Would this graph count as a graph that has a different shortest path tree than minimum spanning tree? Since you could have the shortest path tree start at the vertex that has a heavier edge to the other vertex.

Edit: the question I’m trying to solve is to draw the graph with the smallest number of vertices that has a different minimum spanning tree than shortest path tree, you already allowed to draw any kind of graph.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "Would it count" by whose standards? I would say no, because it's not a graph: it's a directed graph. Minimum spanning trees in particular are a weird concept to discuss for directed graphs.

Comment: What is meant bgy "shortest path tree"? Does it mean you single out one vertex, and you ask for a tree giving the shortest path from that particular vertex to each of the other vertices?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes that is what is meant by shortest path tree

Comment: OK. Then it's easy to construct an example with a 3-vertex undirected graph, right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes that is possible, but is that the smallest possible graph that has a different minimum spanning tree than shortest path tree?

Comment: Well, if you accept the argument from user @Misha, then it can't be done with two vertices, so....